# Error when using Console.ReadLine to display character set

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to c# programming, I have been working on a simple program but have hit a block. The code works fine when I use `Console.Read()` however it only displays the *first character of the user input*, When I try to user `Console.ReadLine` it is highlighted as a *compile time error*

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string to int'.

I have supplied the code below if someone could help me.

```
StringBuilder idnum = new StringBuilder();
int i, count = 0;

while ((i = Console.Read() != 9)
{ 
  if (++count <= 9);
    Console.WriteLine("Error Character count exceeded");

  idnum.Append((char)i);

  break;
}
```

I need the program to display the enter character input.

Comment: In order to display the read character just do Console.WriteLine(i); in the while loop.
If you want to display the string builded with input just print the string builder Console.WriteLine(idnum);

When you do ReadLine you are reading a string and you need to add an explicit cast to get an integer. Using for example Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: What is the intention of the program? Do you simply want to display the user input?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you want to read an *integer* `value` (say, `123`); however, a naive code like

```
int value = Console.ReadLine(); // compile time error here
```

*doesn't compile*, since `Console.ReadLine()` returns `string`, not `int`. You can try to `Parse` the input value with a help of `int.TryParse` until correct input provided:

```
int value = 0; // initialization : let compiler be happy

// keep on asking until valid input is provided
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Please, input an integer value");

  // read input and try to parse it
  if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
    break; // break, if input is a valid integer

  // int.TryParse returned false - parsing failed - let user know it
  Console.WriteLine("Sorry, it's not an integer value. Please, try again.");
}

// from now on, value contains an integer input from user
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Read()` returns the *first* character from the input as an `int`, that is why it works. `Console.ReadLine()`, on the other hand, returns the input `string` until a new line character is found (which usually corresponds to the Enter key being pressed). This means you cannot directly assign its return value to i, as the compiler tells you. Use the `Convert` class and its methods to conveniently convert a type to the one you need, e.g. `i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`. Bear in mind that this might cause exceptions if the conversion fails, i.e. the string does not contain numeric characters only.
As pointed out by Giovanni Patruno in the comments, use `Console.WriteLine(...)` to display your variables. The `ToString()` method inherited from `object` is implicitly called on them for you, as it is in Java, to display them as strings.